# Keycloak asp.net authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, keycloak

Have anybody got Keycloak idm working with .net mvc. I have project where I should make bearer token authentication on Keycloak. I've been searching allover internet and there's like zero implementations on mvc.  Google and ms azure seems to work out of the box.

Thanks
Jari

Comment: I'm also looking for an example with mvc in .net. I found an initial start point for integration here -> https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication

Comment: and maybe this repository has some information for you -> https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples